# Retrieving latest Push Notification if app was not launched by hitting the 'View' button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit

I'm wondering if there is any way of retrieving the last-received push notification if the app is launched from the home screen instead of by pressing the 'View' button on the notification.

The app we're writing is for dealing with sensitive data, and it's important to be able for the central server to be able to remotely disable a client at will, without having the requirement that the app needs an internet connection to launch.

The basic idea I came up for this would be to send a push notification with a custom payload letting the app know to disable itself until it can properly sync its data.

This would work if the user pressed View on the notification, but not if they cancelled it and then launched the app separately.

I'd love to know if this is possible, or otherwise if there's a better way to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Your app would have to connect to the server on launch and get its latest status from there. If your use case is that sensitive, push notifications are probably not reliable enough anyway because Apple does not guarantee that a push notification will actually be delivered.

Comment: Yeah, I know that they're not entirely reliable, but I guess it's more of an "it's better than nothing" solution, to catch a certain percentage of cases and then have to resort to waiting for an internet connection for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ole said, not possible.

Note that you shouldn't be relying on push notifications for anything like this. From Apple's [push notifications programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html):

```
Remember that delivery of notifications is “best effort” and is not guaranteed.
```